# Scrolling issue on IOS (Safari and Chrome) adaptive website - start to occurred last month

Tags: ios, mobile, vertical-scrolling

My client was getting emails from his clients saying they can't scroll the page properly on mobile, I checked it and they are right (on IOS only)

This is the website
[www.checkupkit.com/phone/cat-home-m.html](https://www.checkupkit.com/phone/cat-home-m.html)

The site was built using Adobe Muse around 2015 and wasn't updated since then

I would like some help to find an easy-to-embed solution before I am rebuilding it or change it

Thank you